# Why is there a large stone area in my desert?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So after loading a new map for 1.8 I found a desert. In the desert is a few spots where there is no sand but a blank stone face with assorted dirt, coal, etc. There is sand nearby and it gradually drops to this spot. The average height of these are y = 66. Is this just a feature of the desert biome or do others have this feature too?

[image: Stone in my desert]

Also you can see it across the river in my forest biome.

Comment: Screenshots of this would make it easier to see what's happening.

Comment: I've seen similar spots all around the world since `1.7.3`. I always thought that this would be somekind of feature, though, could be a calculation int he algorithm gone wrong, too.

Comment: Looking at your screenshots, this is REALLY remarkable - I've never seen this much stone in one place.  Still, it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Like in real life*, sometime the terrain generator makes spots of exposed stone on the surface.  This seems a bit counterintuitive in a desert, but it can happen in any biome.

Answer (score 4):

> Occasionally, instead of being converted to dirt or sand, the top
>   layer is stripped away, leaving a 'Basin' of bare stone. There is a
>   common misconception in the community that these are errors, however
>   they are an intended feature. They bear some resemblance to a
>   geological 'shield' (an area of tectonically stable rock that has been
>   exposed to prolonged erosion due to its very old age; it is distinct
>   from the geological term "basin"). They seem to be more common in
>   Forest or Plains, and are sometimes seen filled with water. Sometimes,
>   common minerals can be found on the surface such as coal and iron ore.

Quoted From the (Unofficial) Minecraft Wiki.[image: A Large Basin in a Plains/Forest Biome]